# Hard shifting on SRAM Rival FD shifter

Tags: shifter, sram, front

I just installed SRAM Rival shifters and a FD on my touring bike. However, I'm having an issue with very hard shifting. The right/rear shifts fine (teamed with X7 RD). 
I have to push excessively hard for it to shift to the big ring. Then when I want to drop it to the small ring, again, I have to push hard and it lets loose with 2 very loud, jarring clicks.  I have Rival on my race bike so I KNOW that's not normal.

It almost feels as if the limiter is in too far, not allowing it to reach full throw, but if I let out the limiter, it overshifts and drops the chain. The shifter works fine when the cable is detached.

The previous setup was an ultegra 9sp clamp-on FD. I bought an Origin8 Braze-on Clamp on which to mount the Rival FD.
I'm just afraid I might break the DT blade off over time.  Any ideas on how to remedy this, or what might be causing it? The only thing I can think of is that maybe the Braze-on clamp displaces the FD too far outboard.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some pics of your FD from various angles?

Comment: I'll  post some tonight when I get home from my 2nd job. After some further research today, I have a few things to check when I get home.

Comment: Why did you buy a braze on FD + clamp-on to braze-on adapter rather than just buying the clamp on FD?

Comment: @Batman, They didn't have the size I needed at my source. I needed a 28.6 and all they had was 31.8 & 34.9.

Comment: @ebrohman, Fixed it.
I had the cable going underneath that little notch.  I looked at my other bike and noticed it going over the notch.  Once I switched it, it worked much smoother. 
![link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m21hro8obwnb6jj/2015-09-15%2021.34.36.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed.  It turns out that I had the cable running underneath the notch on the FD. I checked my other bike out and and noticed it running over top of the notch.  Once I switched it, I started shifting much more smoothly. 
[image]

Comment: It would be good if you added a picture of the correct setup or something and then accepted your own answer